# How to open Modal Dialog by clicking on link inside email

Tags: 2010

I have a javascript function inside my custom.js and its included in masterpage. I am using a product called Nintex workflow which shoots an email to the approver and inside email body i want to include a hyperlink and upon clicking on hyperlink it should open a SP.UI.MODAL Dialog and open my page inside.

Is it possible to open a modal dialog from outlook email??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it's not possible, because the javascript is not interpreted in outlook, and it's fortunate for security reason.

The best you can do is to add `&IsDlg=1` argument in your url to open the link like a dialog, but this will still be in a browser window.